# Visual Studio 2008 closes immediately when opening RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, rdlc

I don't know if I can really get an answer to this question ..

Scenario:-  when i m opening solution the RDLC hasn't any problem and the design loads on screen ..  but after building the solution ,
 if i try  for opening  RDLC,   visual studio closes unexpectly . It's a pretty large solution which contain around more than 230 RDLC report

i m using C# language  and my system RAM is 8 gb

any Ideas ?....

Comment: Disable all visual studio plugins and extensions and try again.

Comment: Doesn't matter how much RAM you have - Visual Studio is a 32-bit application with a maximum process size of 2GB. That's for everything - the IDE, plugins and loaded files. You may want to break the project up into multiple projects. (And, as @StingyJack said, disable your plugins)

Comment: @Cyborgx37 : i m not using any plugins , also tried reinstalling Visual studio 2008 ..

Comment: Use the Task Manager and watch how large the Visual Studio process gets. If you hit anywhere near 2 GB, it could explain why it's shutting down. Like I said, you may need to break up your reports into multiple projects.

Comment: You may also want to try opening the solution in VS 2010, just to to see if it works (there were many large solution performance improvements in VS 2010).

Answer (score 0):

scenario:- when i m opening solution the RDLC hasn't any problem and the design loads on screen .. but after building the solution , if i try for opening RDLC, visual studio closes immediately

Solution:-
But When i Removed  ' Environment.exit(-1) '

The issue Get solved .. But i don't know The Real reason why the issue happens only for  all RDLC  report after building the solution ..